# how to disable SSL/TLS compression

Tags: php, apache, ssl

For "SSL/TLS CRIME attack" problem, I need to disable the SSL/TLS compression option in my apache server. Tell your comments.

Comment: Its server configuration doubt only, some of stomach firing persons are close my question. Most of the tech team got same of my config problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`SSLCompression off`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcompression)  in your Apache Httpd configuration. This may be the default value depending on the version you use.

Comment: can you please tell where I need to update this code ( httpd.config / .htaccess ) file ?

Comment: Apache config file httpd.config.